# Modifying view location for partial views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to have both these views:

- ~/Views/Customer/Index.**aspx**
- ~/Views/Customer/Index.**ascx**

I would like to setup my MVC website so that when I call `return View(viewModel)` from the `CustomerController.Index()` action method, that it looks up the **aspx** file, but if I call `return PartialView(viewModel)` that it looks up the **ascx** file.

I believe the magic involves subclassing `ViewEngine` and `ControllerFactory` (so that the `ViewLocator.ViewLocationFormats` can be modified), but want to check that I'm not over-engineering this solution.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Sorry for not being able to provide an answer, but what's PartialView() there for anyway? I thought the point was to provide the fuctionality you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why not just call them different names?

Comment: I second @JcMalta's suggestion. You're probably best renaming Index.ascx to something like IndexPartial.ascx. Why re-invent the wheel if you're going to return a PartialView for it anyway?

Comment: I think my answer to a different question may provide some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363847/render-partial-of-same-name-as-parent-view-crashes-webdev-webserver40-exe/3364288#3364288. The issue is that the partial view locations are set to be the same as the viewlocations.

Comment: @Ahmad, you could link to your other answer in the answer.  Hate to see you not get accepted for this because you have the perfect solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above and the suggestion, I think my answer to a different question may provide some help - [Render Partial of same name as parent View - Crashes WebDev.WebServer40.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363847/render-partial-of-same-name-as-parent-view-crashes-webdev-webserver40-exe/3364288#3364288)

The issue is that the `PartialViewLocationFormats`  are set to be the same as the `ViewLocationFormats`. It does not make sense to that a partial view would be an aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

override `WebFormsViewEngine` and reimplement `ViewLocationFormats` and/or `PartialViewLocationFormats`