# Register RazorViewEngine only for C# (only for .cshtml files)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, global-asax

I am only using `RazorViewEngine` on one of my ASP.NET MVC 3 applications and I cleared Web Forms view engine out with following code inside `Application_Start` method of my **Global.asax.cs** file

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

I decided to see something solid so that I could be satisfied with this two-line-code-effort and I try to render a partial view which does not exist and I got this result :

> The partial view '_ResortMapPartialView' was not found or no view
>   engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:
>   ~/Areas/Accommodation/Views/resort/_ResortMapPartialView.cshtml
>   ~/Areas/Accommodation/Views/resort/_ResortMapPartialView.vbhtml
>   ~/Areas/Accommodation/Views/Shared/_ResortMapPartialView.cshtml
>   ~/Areas/Accommodation/Views/Shared/_ResortMapPartialView.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/resort/_ResortMapPartialView.cshtml
>   ~/Views/resort/_ResortMapPartialView.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/_ResortMapPartialView.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/_ResortMapPartialView.vbhtml

It looks a little better. Now it looks for less items than before. But still the files with `.vbhtml` extensions are making me unconformable.

The question is that : How can we get rid of them?

Comment: @JeremyMcGee I know. the thing that I did is also nearly has no performance improvement (maybe a millisecond) but still an improvement. I am thinking unprofessionally here and seeing less item on that list makes me feel right :) (**NOTE :** I'm not insane, at least not yet.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion would be to override the `RazorViewEngine` definitions for the following to only include `cshtml` files.

- AreaViewLocationFormats
- AreaMasterLocationFormats
- AreaPartialViewLocationFormats
- ViewLocationFormats
- MasterLocationFormats
- PartialViewLocationFormats
- FileExtensions

An brief example:

```
public class CSHtmlViewEngine: RazorViewEngine
{
    public CSHtmlViewEngine()
    {
        base.AreaViewLocationFormats=
            new string[]
                {
                    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
                };

        base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats =
            new string[]
                {
                    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                };

   // All the other LocationFormats listed above will also need to be amended
   // Don't forget the FileExtensions array
   }
```

}

See my answer which [talks about overriding these values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363847/render-partial-of-same-name-as-parent-view-crashes-webdev-webserver40-exe/3364288#3364288). The same principle applies. You will need to register this modified ViewEngine (`CSHtmlViewEngine`) in the `ApplicationStart` method

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CSHtmlViewEngine());
```

Comment: what are {0}, {1}, {2} stand for there? Action, Controller and Area?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing the RazorViewEngine, or replacing it outright, you can just alter existing RazorViewEngine's PartialViewLocationFormats property.  This code goes in Application_Start:

```
System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine rve = (RazorViewEngine)ViewEngines.Engines
  .Where(e=>e.GetType()==typeof(RazorViewEngine))
  .FirstOrDefault();

string[] additionalPartialViewLocations = new[] { 
  "~/Views/[YourCustomPathHere]"
};

if(rve!=null)
{
  rve.PartialViewLocationFormats = rve.PartialViewLocationFormats
    .Union( additionalPartialViewLocations )
    .ToArray();
}
```