# How does RenderPartial figure out where to find a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Ok. Googling fail probably and I remember reading about this a while back but can't find it.

I have a View and a Partial View in different directories.  In a view I say `@Html.RenderPartial("[partial view name]");`  how does RenderPartial figure out where to look?  It must be a convention but what is it?

My view is in: `WebRoot\Views\Admin\` folder and partial is at `WebRoot\Views\Admin\Partials`

Not sure if this the right set up.

I'm using MVC 3 (Razor engine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can, but you have to register the routes, to tell the view engine where to look for.  example in Global.asax.cs you'll have:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RDDBViewEngine());
```

and the class is:

```
public class RDDBViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    private static string[] NewPartialViewFormats = new[] {         
        "~/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml" ,       
        "~/Views/{0}.cshtml"
    };

    public RDDBViewEngine()
    {
        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(NewPartialViewFormats).ToArray();
    }

}
```

*{0}* is for all the subfolders with partials.

Answer (score 3):

Locating views is the responsibility of the ViewEngine. The WebFormViewEngine was the one originally shipped with MVC 1, and you can see the paths it searches [on codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70574#266536). Note that it searches the same paths for views and partial views.

The CshtmlViewEngine (Razor) introduced with MVC 3 (or rather WebMatrix) searches similar locations but looks for different extensions.

Comment: So since PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;  there isn't a way to separate Partial views from Views into different folders? Wouldn't it be nice to say here is a folder with my partials and here is a folder with my views. In web forms I'd have 'controls' directory and I'd put my user .ascx controls there.

Comment: You can put partial views in different folders, but will then need to use a different ViewEngine. This is actually much more simple than it sounds. Just derive from the CshtmlViewEngine in MVC 3 and override the PartialViewLocationFormats property to return the desired search locations. Note that the search locations are format strings in which things like controller, action or area is inserted.  You will also need to register your new ViewEngine with MVC in some bootstrapping method (e.g. Application_Start).

Comment: This questions also seems relevant to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634241/register-razorviewengine-only-for-c-only-for-cshtml-files

Comment: I wonder why ASP.NET team chose to have partials in same directory as views.

Comment: Probably because they could be identified by extension (.ascx for partials and .aspx for views). I actually like it, as it allows you to put all things related in a single folder, which in turn makes it easier to track down where to edit stuff. That said, my own ViewEngine scans the entire Views folder recursively for places to look on startup, as I like putting things into subfolders ;)

Answer (score 1):

Each view engine registered in your application has a list of file patterns that will be searched when you reference a view using a simple name (you can also reference it using a full path e.g. `~\Views\Admin\View.aspx`)

In MVC 3 the [properties of the view engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.virtualpathproviderviewengine_properties%28v=VS.98%29.aspx) specify the patterns to search for (this applies to Razor and WebForms view engines).

Comment: Looking at the code http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70574#266536  PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;   So does this mean I can't (by default) put my partial views in different folder from the views?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subclassing the RazorView engine (as was suggested by zdrsh) you can just alter existing RazorViewEngine's PartialViewLocationFormats property.  This code goes in Application_Start:

```
System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine rve = (RazorViewEngine)ViewEngines.Engines
  .Where(e=>e.GetType()==typeof(RazorViewEngine))
  .FirstOrDefault();

string[] additionalPartialViewLocations = new[] { 
  "~/Views/[YourCustomPathHere]"
};

if(rve!=null)
{
  rve.PartialViewLocationFormats = rve.PartialViewLocationFormats
    .Union( additionalPartialViewLocations )
    .ToArray();
}
```