# How to use Html.Partial() method to render partial view with an explicit path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

Everyone,  I'm using MVC 3 (Razor).  I have the following problem:

I have some common contents segregated into a partial view.  But rather than to put it in the default location (`views/shared` or `views/controller-name`), I need to put it in a different location (`views/shared/new-folder` or `view/controller-name/new-folder`).

I tried this : `@Html.Partial("views/shared/new-folder/partial-view-name")` or even `@Html.Partial("views/shared/new-folder/partial-view-name.cshtml")`,but it seems that MVC3 only consider the parameter as a view name, and it totally ignored any path information.

Maybe I did something wrong ,can anybody help me with this ?:) Thank you very much!

Comment: here is the same question

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640790/how-does-renderpartial-figure-out-where-to-find-a-view/7641165#7641165][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640790/how-does-renderpartial-figure-out-where-to-find-a-view/7641165#7641165

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to reference using an application virtual path (notice the `~\` at the beginning of the path):

```
@Html.Partial("~\\views\\shared\\new-folder\\partial-view-name.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have also configured an action to return that Partial View, You could also do:

`@{ Html.RenderAction("PartialViewAction", "PartialViewCOntroller");}`

This is probably better since you shouldn't be hard coding references to Views in your code. Deploying a hard coded reference on a different server could break the application, but calling an action to return a view won't.